# How to filter by email_address domain with exchangelib?

Tags: python, exchangelib

I'm having the following problem to get the emails.
Also, I want to filter emails by email_address domain.

Code:

```
from exchangelib import Q
from exchangelib import Account, Configuration, Credentials, DELEGATE, errors
...

account = connect(SERVER_URL, EMAIL, PASSWORD)

# Get the folder object
folder = account.root / 'Top of Information Store' / 'Inbox'

# Get emails
q = (Q(subject__contains='key_word') and Q(sender__contains='mydomain1.com'))
emails = folder.all().filter(q)

for item in emails:
  print(item.subject)
```

Output:

```
(Nothing Prints)
```

Answer (score 0):

`__contains` in combination with a list translates to "contains A and B". That's never going to match in your case. You need to use Q objects and boolean operators to get "contains A or B":

```py
from exchangelib import Q

folder.filter(Q(sender__contains='mydomain1.com') | Q(sender__contains='mydomain2.com'))
```

See more at https://ecederstrand.github.io/exchangelib/#searching

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, I want to filter by email address domain instead of subject.

Comment: Just change `subject` to `sender` in my example.

Comment: Work on "sender=who@mydomain.com". 
But didn't work on "sender__contains=mydomain.com"

Comment: Ok, maybe EWS doesn't support "contains" filtering on the "sender" field.